# Cannot see processes spawned with GNOME

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am using ubuntu. When I spawn a process from the Gnome desktop, it does not appear to be visible if I type ps -a in another terminal.

For example, if I launch Chrome or OpenOffice Calc, it is invisible if I open a shell and type ps -a.

Why is that and how can I see these processes?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps ax
```

will show that processes.

---

From the `ps` man page:

> [-]a Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal.

processes started by gnome are not associated with a terminal and therefore will not being displayed

Then man page, again:

> [-]x               Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps
>                          personality setting is BSD-like. The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means. An alternate
>                          description is that this option causes ps to list all processes owned by you (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes when used together with the a option.

Means that option `a` together with option `x` displays all processes